# Reference open Access database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to reference an open Access file from Excel VBA. I'm just having trouble setting it up.

```
Dim Ac As Access.Application
Set Ac = ???

Ac.DoCmd.OpenForm "Blah"
```

What do I put in place of the `???` to reference the open database?

Comment: You may be able to use `GetObject()` - take a look into that

Comment: `Dim AC As Object`
`Set AC = GetObject("<FileLocation>.accdb", "Access.Application")`
`AC.DoCmd.OpenForm "<Blah>"` opens a new Access window, but it does open up the form... (Everything between greater/less than signs isn't actually what I'm using in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetObject(pathname, class)` as [Tim suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530363/reference-open-access-database/32530539#comment52918927_32530363).

```vb
Set Ac = GetObject(, "Access.Application") ' no value for pathname argument
Ac.DoCmd.OpenForm "Blah"
```

If you have more than one Access session open, use the full path of the db file which you want to reference ...

```vb
Set Ac = GetObject("C:\share\Access\Database2.accdb") ' give it pathname
```

You could use late binding instead of `Dim Ac As Access.Application` and avoid the need to set a reference to the Access type library.  With late binding you could declare the variable like this, and `GetObject` will still cooperate ...

```vb
Dim Ac As Object
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! I tried using the pathname, but that opened another Access window which is not what I wanted. Having a blank argument worked!

Comment: I saw your reply to @Tim and investigated further.    `GetObject("C:\share\Access\Database2.accdb", "Access.Application")` gave me a new Access session.  But giving `GetObject` only one of those two arguments did not create a new session.

Comment: When I didn't have the second argument and just had the filepath, it gave an error about it not being a valid database or something, but I didn't have the .accdb ending in the filepath so that probably had something to do with it.